# Issue with installing zendframework2 skeleton

Tags: php, composer-php

i'm new to zendframework 2 , while trying to install it , using composer , it gets installed but an error message appears saying :

Your requirements could  not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem1
      - Installation request for zendframework/zendframework 2.3.* -> satisfiable by zendframework/zendframework[2.3.0].
      - zendframework/zendframework 2.3.0 requires php >=5.3.23 -> no matching package found

knowing that I have php 5.4.3.

Could someone please explain to me what's wrong ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the PHP version you are using for the CLI is using PHP 5.4.3 too. The CLI version can use a different PHP version than the host. You can get the php version used by the console by using the `php --version` command.

Comment: oh you're right , i found out that he is using the version 5.1.13 , but do you know how to set the other version to be used by the cmd ?

Comment: @user3446783 Change the PHP executable your cmd is using. (I assume you're using windows, then take a look at the `PATH` env variable and update it to point to the newer PHP directory)